# Definition - Local area network configuration

Tags: config, lan

What is meant by a local area network configuration, as opposed to a local area network? or any network configuration for that matter.

What does it refer to exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it's name would imply, a LAN configuration refers to the parameters that defines the network, such as the network mask, security protocol in use, access control, IP (if a TCP/IP network) address delivery method,  etc.

Btw this question is quite vague. If you're looking to know more about networks, you should start by some readings, and could possibly try out some online configuration exemple such as [this one](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-lan/index.html)

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: If you're satisfied by this answer, please consider marking it as "accepted", under the downvote arrow :)